# Finding two possible values of $z^2 + z + 1$ given that $z$ is one of the three cube roots of unity.

Tags: complex-numbers

Factorise $z^3 - 1 $.
If $z$ is one of the three cube roots of unity, find the two possible values of $z^2 + z + 1$.

Factorising gives you :

$(z - 1)(z^2 + z + 1) = 0$ since $z$ is one of the three cube roots of unity.

z is complex so $z \neq 1$ so $z-1 \neq 0$

Hence, $z^2 + z + 1 = 0$

Where do I go from here?

Any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 3):

You are done. The two possible values of $z^2+z+1$ are $0$ for $z$ a third root of unity different from $1$, as you have computed, and $1+1+1=3$ for $z=1$.

Comment: Why $z$ = 1????

Comment: Because $z=1$ also satisfies $z^3=1$, hence is a third root of unity. We have 3 different third roots of unity, namely $z=1,e^{2\pi i/3},e^{4\pi i/3}$.

Comment: I really don't get it

Comment: I don't understand why $z=1$ is able to be substituted in, for what reason? Also the answer below gives you a complex root?

Comment: The questions says." If $z$ is one of the **three** cube roots of unity (so $z=1$ for example), find the two possible values of $z^2 + z + 1$." Now do this for $z=1$.

Comment: Why $z = 1$ though? Why not take $z = 2$ or something? This may seem really easy, but I'm quite slow, sorry.

Comment: Dear TripleA: $z=2$ is **not** a third cube of unity, because its third power is **not** $1$. Rather we have $2^3=8\neq 1$. A cube root of unity is a number $z$ with $z^3=1$.

Comment: Then what are the 3 cubes of unity?

Comment: Read the line after your "Why $z=1$?????"

Comment: Ahhhhh so why aren't we subbing in the other two possible values?

Comment: @TripleA You don't need to substitute, because you know that $(z-1)(z^2+z+1)=0$ for the three roots. Therefore either $z-1=0$ or $z^2+z+1=0$. In other words, the two roots that are not $z=1$ must satisfy $z^2+z+1=0$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
0 = z^2 + z + 1 = (z+1/2)^2 - (1/2)^2 + 1 = (z+1/2)^2 + 3/4 \iff \\
z + \frac{1}{2} = \pm i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \iff \\
z = \frac{-1 \pm i \sqrt{3}}{2}
$$
By the way:
$$
1 + z + z^2 = \frac{z^3-1}{z-1}
$$
as a finite term geometric series.

Comment: I'm getting different answers..? Apparently it's 3?

Comment: The third root, $z=1$, you already factored off.

Answer (score 0):

More generally, you have $$(z-1)\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} z^j = z^N-1,$$
so for $z=1$ you have $\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} z^j = N$ and if $z\neq 1$ you get $$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} z^j = \frac{z^N-1}{z-1}.$$ Hence, if $z$ is any $N^{th}$ root of unity not equal to 1, we have $$\sum_{j=0}^{N-1} z^j = 0.$$